# Invalid operand of types 'double' and 'const char[5]' to binary 'operator<<'

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I'm trying to make a C++ Acidity/Base Universal Calculator. Upon trying to finalize my code, I stump upon 5 error(s) below;

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:62:36: error: invalid operands of types 'double' and 'const char [5]' to binary 'operator<<'
    cout << "[H+]=" << 10^(W-X)  << "*10^"  << W << '\n';
                                    ^

main.cpp:63:34: error: invalid operands of types 'int' and 'double' to binary 'operator^'
    cout << "[OH-]=" << 1/(10^(W-X))  << "*10^"  << (-14)-W << '\n'; 
                                  ^
main.cpp:77:33: error: invalid operands of types 'int' and 'double' to binary 'operator^'
    cout << "[H+]=" << 1/(10^(U-V))  << "*10^"  << (-14)-U << '\n';
                                 ^
main.cpp:78:37: error: invalid operands of types 'double' and 'const char [5]' to binary 'operator<<'
    cout << "[OH-]=" << 10^(U-V)  << "*10^"  << U << '\n'; 
                                     ^

D:\EvaxHybrid\Mywork\Cpp\ChempHpOH\Makefile.win:28: recipe for target 'main.o' failed

mingw32-make.exe: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

I've tried implementing [Solution 1 which isn't inline and would make the code too complex to read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20579570/invalid-operands-of-types-double-and-const-char-2-to-binary-operator?rq=1) , [Solution 2 which isn't inline and not the same problem (I didn't use new)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405973/invalid-operands-of-types-c). If there's no other choice, anyone could comment to me about that and I'll do a function related approach.
Here's the code (*main.cpp*);

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Choose Start point..." << '\n';
    cout << "1. [H+]\n2. [OH-]\n3. pH\n4. pOH\n";
    int choice;
    cin >> choice;
    system ("cls");
    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1:
            cout << "Convert [H+] to Scientific Notation of A*10^B and input A,B\n";
            system ("pause");
            cout << '\n';
            double A,B;
            cout << "A:";
            cin >> A;
            cout << '\n';
            cout << "B:";
            cin >> B;
            cout << '\n';
            cout << "[H+]=" << A  << "*10^"  << B << '\n';
            cout << "[OH-]=" << 1/A  << "*10^"  << (-14)-B << '\n'; 
            cout << "[pH]=" << (-log10(A)-B) << '\n';
            cout << "[pOH]=" << 14-(-log10(A)-B) << '\n';
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "Convert [OH-] to Scientific Notation of Z*10^Y and input Z,Y\n";
            system ("pause");
            cout << '\n';
            double Z,Y;
            cout << "Z:";
            cin >> Z;
            cout << '\n';
            cout << "Y:";
            cin >> Y;
            cout << '\n';
            cout << "[H+]=" << 1/Z  << "*10^"  << (-14)-Y << '\n';
            cout << "[OH-]=" << Z  << "*10^"  << Y << '\n'; 
            cout << "[pH]=" << 14-(-log10(Z)-Y) << '\n';
            cout << "[pOH]=" << (-log10(Z)-Y) << '\n';
            break;
        case 3:
            cout << "Input pH as X\n";
            system ("pause");
            cout << '\n';
            double X;
            cout << "X:";
            cin >> X;
            double W;
            W = -ceil(X);
            cout << '\n';
            cout << "[H+]=" << 10^(W-X)  << "*10^"  << W << '\n';
            cout << "[OH-]=" << 1/(10^(W-X))  << "*10^"  << (-14)-W << '\n'; 
            cout << "[pH]=" << X << '\n';
            cout << "[pOH]=" << 14-X << '\n';
            break;
        case 4:
            cout << "Input pOH as V\n";
            system ("pause");
            cout << '\n';
            double V;
            cout << "V:";
            cin >> V;
            double U;
            U = -ceil(V);
            cout << '\n';
            cout << "[H+]=" << 1/(10^(U-V))  << "*10^"  << (-14)-U << '\n';
            cout << "[OH-]=" << 10^(U-V)  << "*10^"  << U << '\n'; 
            cout << "[pH]=" << 14-V << '\n';
            cout << "[pOH]=" << V << '\n';
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: `^` is not power. Fix that, rest of issues should go away.

Comment: `10^(W-X)` doesn't do what you think it does. See your C++ book for more details. You cannot attempt to come up with valid C++ syntax by guessing what it looks like. The only way to know what  it should be is to learn it from a book.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Ok I forgot that `double pow ( double base, double exp );`

Comment: Looks like you might've also forgot that, in C++, the result of dividing 1 by 2 is zero.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Is there a fix for that? or Migrate to C#?

Comment: Of course this can be done correctly: divide 1.0 by 2.0 if your desired result is 0.5, instead of dividing 1 by 2. See your C++ book for a complete list of numerical promotion rules in C++.

Comment: In C#, `1/2` is still `0`. I don't know if there's an issue in your code with this though, since it looks like it's all `int / double` … unless I'm missing one.

Comment: Ok, I'll remind users to add .0 to A then.

Comment: `A` doesn't need `.0`, since its type is `double`... It's the type that matters, not the value

Comment: X:4.7,

[H+]=1.99526e-010*10^-5,
[OH-]=5.01187e+009*10^-9,
[pH]=4.7,
[pOH]=9.3,
How to fix e+009 and make it disappear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Operator `<<` [has precedence over](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) operator `^`.

```
cout << "[H+]=" << 10^(W-X)  << "*10^"  << W << '\n';
```

is read as

```
(cout << "[H+]=" << 10)  ^  ((W-X)  << "*10^"  << W << '\n');
```

Put parenthesis:

```
cout << "[H+]=" << (10^(W-X))  << "*10^"  << W << '\n';
```

Comment: Also, beware that `a^b` generally means a `xor` b. If you want to compute exponents, see `std::pow`.

Comment: Wouldn't `<<` have precedence over `^` since `<<` comes first? (just wording)

Comment: I may have to use std::pow first before applying your solution.

Comment: Ok it is fixed by combining your solution and replacing ^ with pow().

Comment: @ChrisMM I messed with my opening, fixed. _*facepalm*_